# Contact form 7 redirect thank you page and contact form 7 autoresponder not working together

Tags: contact-form-7

although its very nice and simple plugin and working perfectly as per our requirement. but I found an issue here i.e before using this plugin, the contact form 7 was working 2 way means mails were going to both parties i.e admin and user. but after using this redirect thank you page plugin, only admin is getting the mails after form submission and user is not getting any autoresponder mail. perviously it was working perfectly.

hope you understood the issue. please help me with its solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

its solved. actually the issue was with contact form 7 itself not with redirect plugin.